# Kafka job assignment & completion

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have requirement where i receive a record in KafkaStream, I divide this single record into n records based on logic. These n records are pushed to another stream. These n records are processed parallely. But I need to know the completion of n jobs so I can send response back. Can you please let me know how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do it is to set up a consumer to subscribe to that stream and do process it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to know that in fact *"N messages were processed"*. AFAIK, there's not a universal solution for this, but here's what I would do.

(Note: My solution assumes that you have a single consumer consuming the second stream.)

To know that N records have been processed, you have to know what N is. So when you divide the single record into N records, *store that N in the records themselves* (e.g. if your records are JSON objects, add a `"n": 5` key-value pair). Then, in the consumer(s) that process the 2nd stream (the one that contains N records), with each message you consume you do the following:

1. consume message and process message
2. increment a counter (let's call it K) - this could be an in-memory or a persistent storage-backed counter
3. compare K to N

   - if equal, all messages have been processed (at this point you might want to exit)
   - otherwise, there are more messages to be processed; continue consuming